# C++ For loop algorithm

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I'm new to c++ and I need some help with a for loop algorithm in my doubleUp function. The purpose of the doubleUp function is if an array has the same consecutive values, then each number would be doubled. An example is if an array has the elements of 4, 4, 4, and 4. The new array would be 8, 8, 8, 8 by using the doubleUp function. Thanks again guys! :D

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void collectScores(double scores[], int SIZE);
void printScores(double scores[], int stopPlace);
void doubleUp(double scores[], int SIZE);

void collectScores(double scores[], int SIZE)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < SIZE; n++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a value for element " <<  (n) << " : ";
        cin >> scores[n];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void printScores(double scores[], int stopPlace)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < stopPlace; n++)
    {
        cout << "The value of element " << (n) << " : " << scores[n] << endl;
    }
}

void doubleUp(double scores[], int SIZE)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < SIZE; n++)
    {
        if (scores[n] == scores[n + 1])
        {
            scores[n] *= 2;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    double r;
    const int SIZE = 4;
    double scores[SIZE];

    collectScores(scores, SIZE);
    printScores(scores, SIZE);

    cout << endl;

    doubleUp(scores, SIZE);
    printScores(scores, SIZE);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain what your problem and question is. Bow you've only said what you want to do but not what is wrong with your code.

Comment: [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). I can see without trying: Running off the end of the array (undefined behavior) and you'll never double the last one in a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides that you were missing an edge case at the end there is a bigger problem.  Since you're looking ahead, in one direction, for doubles, this means that you will miss doubling the last element of *every* island of adjacent equal numbers.  In my code below I have added a single state variable called `isDouble` which addresses the problem.

```
void doubleUp(double scores[], int SIZE)
{
    if (SIZE < 2) return;        // 0 or 1 element just return
    bool isDouble = false;

    for (int n = 1; n < SIZE; n++)
    {
        if (scores[n] == scores[n - 1])
        {
            isDouble = true;
            scores[n - 1] = 2*scores[n - 1];
        }
        else if (isDouble)
        {
            isDouble = false;
            scores[n - 1] = 2*scores[n - 1];
        }
    }

    // edge case: possibly double the last element in the array
    //            if it be identical to the second to last element
    if (isDouble) scores[SIZE-1] = 2*scores[SIZE-1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As people pointed out,the bug in your code is that your last element is not getting doubled.This is because for the last element in your array, there is no succeeding element and that's where the "n+1" part of your code fails.
There are quite a few ways you can sort out this problem.
I have used two for loops- one for all elements other than the last two elements and the other for the last two elements.

```
void doubleUp(double scores[], int SIZE)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < SIZE-2; n++)
    {
        if (scores[n] == scores[n + 1])
        {
            scores[n] *= 2;
        }
    }
    for (int n = SIZE-2; n <SIZE; n++)
    {
        if (scores[n] == scores[n + 1])
        {
            scores[n] *= 2;
            scores[n+1] *= 2;
        }
    }  
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I believe your doubleUp function should be slightly edited:

```
void doubleUp(double scores[], int SIZE)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < SIZE; n++)
    {
        if (n < SIZE-2)
        {    
            if (scores[n] == scores[n + 1])
            {
                scores[n] *= 2;               
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (scores[n] == scores[n + 1])
            {
                scores[n] *= 2;
                scores[n+1] *= 2;   
                n++;             
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The added section essentially allows the last item in the array to be doubled, where as the original code did not (there is no n+1 index after the last item in the array.)

Comment: You make the exact same mistake as OP, but you do it twice.